# How can I retrieve the page id when using a wxNotebook?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a class named MyListView which is derived from wxListCtrl and this class acts as page for wxNotebook.

```
MyListView* l = new MyListView( m_notebook, -1, m_serverLog, incoming_socket );
m_notebook->AddPage( l, "Log", true );
```

Inside that class it is sometimes necessary to change the caption of the tab displayed by wxNotebook.

According to the documentation, this is the function to use:

> **wxNotebook::SetPageText**
>
> `bool SetPageText(size_t page, const wxString& text)`
>
> Sets the text for the given page.

The problem is, at this time it is not necessarily the currently selected page.

**What is the best way to find out which id the page currently has by which it can be identified by above function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since wxWidgets 2.9.5 you can use [notebook->FindPage(this)](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_book_ctrl_base.html#a098c7ea66b5328bee5ce06d9c973fbc1) to find the index of the page in the notebook. In the previous version you could just loop over all the notebook pages yourself to find the one you're interested in (as this is what `FindPage()` does anyhow).

Finally, quite often you are working with the currently visible page only, in which case you can use [notebook->GetSelection()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_book_ctrl_base.html#a42b7d557ec288a1819b024613adf6315) instead.

Comment: I feel stupid now. I had 2.9.5 downloaded, was using the docs for 2.9.5 and was trying to use FindPage already, which gave me only error messages. Now I found out that I actually never installed/compiled 2.9.5 :D. Thanks for your answer nonetheless :D